# Best book on logic puzzles

Tags: discrete-mathematics, reference-request, book-recommendation

I am learning discrete mathematics and to develop logic most people advised me to solve logical puzzles. Can anyone suggest me some good books on logical puzzles?

Comment: I just wanted to be specific among puzzles with math analysis,physics puzzles,computer puzzles etc.

Comment: I'm not so good at Kenken, that can do the job too but i'm looking for questions which should be solved with logic.

Comment: There is a wide variety of deductive puzzles similar to Kenken.  Are you looking specifically for puzzles of that style?  (Where the rule set is very small and precisely defined, rather than inferred from general knowledge.)

Answer (score 1):

Books by Smullyan come to mind.  For instance, The Goedelian Puzzle Book.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have good grip on logical mathematics then I would prefer Ross Honsburger.

Read his collection which mainly consist of 3 volumes of Mathematical Gems and Mathematical circles.